# Traverse table on database side to compare password hashed by bcrypt

Tags: python, mysql, flask, hash, bcrypt

On the login route i retrieve the password. How do i find the user with the matching hashed password in the database without fetching the whole user table and traverse it on the server?

In mysql every user has a hashed password from registering. I generated it like this: `bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt()).decode('utf-8')`

If i execute the same method at login (for the same plain-text password) i get a different hash.

So something like this:

```
select * from User where hash_generated_at_register = hash_generated_at_login
```

Fails, even if the plain-text password used in the login and register step is the same.

From what i understand password checking in bcrypt is done by `bcrypt.checkpw(password, hash)` instead of hashing again. Using this approach the only options i can think of is to select the whole User table and travserse it on the server side. But i want to to the traversal on the db-side! How do i accomplish this using the bcrypt hashing method?

Comment: If you can generate the hash with `bcrypt` then sure that hash in a variable.  Do a select on your password database that uses that hash.  Something like

    `select * from password_tabke where encrypted_password = your_saved_hash`

Of course please use the correct query parameterization scheme for the language you are using

Comment: Well, you probably have the user id along with the password when the user tries to log in. You need to retrieve that user's password and compare it to that hashed version.

Comment: But the hashpw returns a different hash for the same input everytime! The hash in the database from the register step is different from the hash in the login step, even though it's the same input...

Comment: @Shadow yes ofcourse, that would be the better approach actually. There is no need to query the database with the hash i realize now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole way bcrypt works is that it gives you a value that combines the hashed password and salt into one value for you to store.

This means that you cannot recreate the hash from the password without the salt, which you do not have.

You need to select the user from the database via some `user_id` that you may have, and then use the bcrypt library to compare your password with the combined value that you have stored.

```
bcrypt.hashpw(password, hash_and_salt_value_from_db)
```

You can use the same function you used to create the "hash", but instead pass in your stored value. The function is smart enough to realise that it is a hash+salt and will extract and use the salt for you.

So you then want to check

```
if hash_and_salt_value_from_db == bcrypt.hashpw(password, hash_and_salt_value_from_db):
    # tada, valid password
```

Shout if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: yes ofcourse, that would be the better approach actually. There is no need to query the database with the hash i realize now...

Answer (score 1):

Modern security encryption assigns a unique salt (random string) to each user so that if some user, say Alice, signs up to you website and uses the password "password" then the hashed database entry she will be assigned is:

```
Hash("password" + "random_string_for_alice") = "HASH_VALUE:MD51000:random_string_for_alice"
```

Here the hash string includes the hashing algorithm (MD5)x1000 iterations and the salt used ("random_string_for_alice")

Now if you are just supplied a password - only a password and not a username - in order to find out whose (if any) username it belongs to you will have to look at each user's hashed password, extract the public salt and apply the iteration and then compare it. You will need to do this for each user in the database to find the answer.

And this is, of course, the point of modern password encryption recommendation..

Comment: what?! this will be a very expensive operation!

Comment: @CageE are you suggesting this doesn't occur because it absolutely does, or are you expressing surprise. Its not that computer intensive each time, but the point is to be intensive enough that a password cracker that scans 250bn hashes per second doesn't have enough time to crack a database entry.